# How to reconfigure sharing printer to clients pc?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, printer, network-printer

Sorry for bad english...

I have a client who is sharing a printer from a pc (windows 8.1) and have other 3 pcs (windows 7) conected to that printer. I disconnected the printer to check it and then connected again to the pc, suddenly the other 3 pcs stopped printing, I don't know why nor how to configure back the other 3 pcs

Main pc: windows 8.1
Clients: windows 7
Printer: hp officejet pro k8600

What i have done is

- remove device and add it again
- stop and restart spooler
- reinstall printer on main pc
- install new drivers on main pc
- stop and restart spooler deleting files
- using various methods of adding printers

None seems working for me

What else am i missing?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the printer on the client PCs?

Comment: Yes, i tried that too

Answer (score 0):

Try a complete reinstall on all PCs.

Go to Devices and Printers. Delete the printer. Then go to Control Panel > Uninstall programs and remove anything relating to the printer. Go back to Devices & Printers, click on any other printer (even the XPS driver will do) and then on "Print Server Properties" from the menu that appears. Click the Drivers tab and remove the printer from the list.

Then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

When removing the printer, the printer connection may not be removed as well. If you reinstall the printer, this, now faulty, connection may be reused. You can manage this using MMC (printmanagement.msc / Print Management). First remove the printer, then the connection.